# How to sum the values in a column based on another column or different group?

Tags: mysql, sum, rowid

For  example, I have a table1:

```
+---------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| StartTime           | dIPaddr       |  countNum     |       rowid   |
+---------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| 2014-04-09 09:47:53 | 0.210.208.240 |       2       |         1     |
| 2014-04-09 09:47:54 | 0.210.208.240 |       0       |         2     |
| 2014-04-09 09:47:55 | 0.210.208.240 |       1       |         3     |
| 2014-04-09 08:39:55 | 0.210.243.93  |       1       |         1     |
| 2014-04-09 08:39:56 | 0.210.243.93  |       0       |         2     |
| 2014-04-09 08:39:57 | 0.210.243.93  |       1       |         3     |
| 2014-04-09 13:02:25 | 0.210.25.224  |       3       |         1     |
| 2014-04-09 13:02:26 | 0.210.25.224  |       0       |         2     |
| 2014-04-09 13:02:27 | 0.210.25.224  |       1       |         3     |
+---------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

The rowid is based on different dIPaddr, in each dIPaddr group, it has rowid ordered by StartTime.
I use this command to add rowid for them:

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ADD COLUMN rowId int not null auto_increment,
ADD PRIMARY KEY(dIPaddr, rowId),
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

I want to sum each dIPaddr's first countNum up, sum each dIPaddr's second countNum up,sum each dIPaddr's third countNum up.
If use Pseudo-code， it should look like:

```
dIPaddr(0.210.208.240).rowid(1).countNum+dIPaddr(0.210.243.93).rowid(1).countNum+dIPaddr(0.210.25.224).rowid(1).countNum

dIPaddr(0.210.208.240).rowid(2).countNum+dIPaddr(0.210.243.93).rowid(2).countNum+dIPaddr(0.210.25.224).rowid(2).countNum

dIPaddr(0.210.208.240).rowid(3).countNum+dIPaddr(0.210.243.93).rowid(3).countNum+dIPaddr(0.210.25.224).rowid(3).countNum
```

So the final table should look like:

```
+-------+
| count |
+-------+
|     6 |
|     0 |
|     3 |
+-------+
```

I am a very new student for using database, sorry for my simple question. Thanks for everyone's help!
By the way, above is just a simple example of my real database, actually, each dIPaddr has more than 100 records for their rowid. So I cannot just use limit 3 to so some simple calculations.

Comment: `select sum(countNum) as total,rowid from table1 group by rowid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(countNum) as Total FROM tbl_name GROUP BY rowid
```

Comment: In fact, each dIPaddr has different range of rowid, for example, A only have rowid ranges from 1~10, B has rowid ranges from 1~5. The minimum rowid of each of their largest rowid is 5, so I only want to sum that untill their rowid is 5. So what should I do?   SELECT SUM(countNum) as Total FROM tbl_name GROUP BY rowid limit 5? or SELECT SUM(countNum) as Total FROM tbl_name GROUP BY rowid having rowid<=5?

Comment: please try <=5 query, or can you try query with group by dIPaddr?